# SQL How to insert and select data from multiple tables into a single table and using different colomns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am working on a school project and i have the following tables:

**table1**

projectcode

projectname

**table2**

paymentcode

description

**table3**

projectcode

paymentcode

price

date

Now i've made a form with the inputs: projectname, discription price and date. Also projectname and discription are dropdownmenus linked with the database and contains exisitng data. Now what i want to know is how can i fill table 3 with those four inputs. Ofcourse price and date are easy since thats only a matter of INSERT but my problem is: how can i get the projectcode inserted in table3 by only selecting the projectname? its the same for discription.

example: I'm selecting projectname1 from the projectname dropdownmenu in my form and hit submit. then looking at table3 i should see projectname1's projectcode. 
Long story short:
 im looking for a way to make a relationship somehow between two columns in this case projectname and projectcode.

I hope anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand you. 
In a dropdownlist, there should be a key-value pair, in which key = Id (ProjectCode), and value = Name (ProjectName).

Your query should look like below:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (ProjectCode, PaymentCode, Price, Date)
(
    SELECT ProjectCode, NULL, @PriceFromYourInput, @DateFromYourInput
    FROM Table1 WHERE ProjectName = @ProjectNameFromYourDropdown
)
```

Do you have mapping between Table1 and Table2 ?
Otherwise, you need to specify, for a certain project X (Table1.ProjectCode), how much does it cost (Table2.PaymentCode). If you want to put the mapping in Table3, you have to input PaymentCode from dropdown too.

Your query should look like below:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (ProjectCode, PaymentCode, Price, Date)<br />
(
    SELECT ProjectCode, PaymentCode, @PriceFromYourInput, @DateFromYourInput
    FROM
    Table1 WHERE ProjectName = @ProjectNameFromYourDropdown
    OUTER JOIN
    Table2 WHERE Description = @PaymentNameFromYourDropdown
)
```